# When does Deadpool figure out he can grow back parts?

Tags: marvel, comics, deadpool

In the movie he cuts off his own arm, and at this point he has only been Deadpool for almost a year, yet he still recognizes that he is able to heal from just about anything.

But being able to grow body parts and heal cancer is two different things, when does he realize he can grow back actual parts?

I'm looking for more of a canon answer, I don't think we can figure it out from the movie.

Comment: Yes, in the movie it was not made clear as in at what point of time, he actually comes to know that he can regenerate...

Comment: Right, but I bet he went into that knowing he would regenerate the arm since we he did in such a casual way

Comment: I'd assume in the film it was when he got his body burned off.

Comment: I'm still wondering how his body is able to restore pretty much anything in the proper dimensions and shape, yet fails at his skin. ;)

Comment: I don't know, but this being Deadpool I hope someone comes up with some horrible innuendo regarding "growing parts".

Comment: @EricSSH *"..grow body parts and heal cancer.."* The cancer is ***not*** 'healed'. It is just that the new powers are in 'balance' with it.

Comment: The first answer is good from a movie perspective, but this seems to be asking about the comics. There's no movie tag, for instance. Not sure if I should upvote that answer.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, at 48m 20s, Francis proclaims to Wade:

> I've cured you Wade. Now your mutated cells can heal anything.

Then, around the 50m 30s mark, we see Wade escape the torture chamber by lighting the oxygen on fire with the match previously obtained. After a short fight with Francis, we see Wade impaled almost through the heart with a large metal rod. Shortly after, as he rises from the ashes, we hear his voiceover saying:

> I didn't just the cure to el cancer, I got the cure to el everything

After this, he goes looking for Francis in a white ski mask and jumper, where he gets shot a couple of times, turning nonchalantly toward the shooter. His attitude towards getting shot clearly suggests that he's aware of this outcome, and it doesn't bother him. Due to this, we can assume that he figures it out before this point, likely as he rose from the ashes of the burning building.

Potentially graphic picture below, if you're not ok with it

> [image]